# Shuffle data in Pandas Dataframe from a column to another in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe named 'df', which has 29 columns. An example of the dataframe i am working with, with a few less columns to visualise it in a better way would be:

| tourney_name | draw_size | player1_id | player1_age | player2_id | player2_age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 32 | 10001 | 23 | 10002 | 18 |
| A | 32 | 10003 | 24 | 10004 | 30 |
| A | 32 | 10005 | 25 | 10006 | 28 |
| B | 64 | 10003 | 24 | 10002 | 18 |
| B | 64 | 10006 | 28 | 10001 | 23 |

The df as is now, all the players in the player1 columns are the ones that won the match and players in player2 columns are the ones that lost that match.

I need a resulting df that shuffles randomly some of the player data in some of the rows so that i can add a 'target' variable, which shows '1' if the player in the player1 columns is the one that won the match or '0' if the player in the player1 columns lost the match.
The resulting df should be something like this:

| tourney_name | draw_size | player1_id | player1_age | player2_id | player2_age | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 32 | 10001 | 23 | 10002 | 18 | 1 |
| A | 32 | 10004 | 30 | 10003 | 24 | 0 |
| A | 32 | 10006 | 28 | 10005 | 25 | 0 |
| B | 64 | 10003 | 24 | 10002 | 18 | 1 |
| B | 64 | 10001 | 23 | 10006 | 28 | 0 |

To do what I need I created this code:

```
# Create a new DataFrame for modeling
model_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate through each row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Randomly assign the winner and loser information to Player1 and Player2
    common_cols = ['tourney_name', 'draw_size', 'tourney_level', 'tourney_date', 'best_of', 'round', 'minutes', 'surface_Carpet', 'surface_Clay', 'surface_Grass', 'surface_Hard']
    common_data = row[common_cols]

    winner_cols = ['player1_id', 'player1_seed', 'player1_entry', 'player1_hand', 'player1_ht', 'player1_ioc', 'player1_age', 'player1_rank', 'player1_rank_points']
    loser_cols = ['player2_id', 'player2_seed', 'player2_entry', 'player2_hand', 'player2_ht', 'player2_ioc', 'player2_age', 'player2_rank', 'player2_rank_points']

    # Randomly choose winner and loser columns
    if np.random.rand() < 0.5:
        winner_data = row[winner_cols]
        loser_data = row[loser_cols]
        target = 1  # Player1 is the winner
    else:
        winner_data = row[loser_cols]
        loser_data = row[winner_cols]
        target = 0  # Player1 is the loser

    combined_data = pd.concat([common_data, winner_data, loser_data, pd.Series([target], name='target')], axis=0)
    model_df = pd.concat([model_df, combined_data], axis=1)

model_df = model_df.transpose()

# Renaming the column '0' to 'target'
model_df.rename(columns={0: 'target'}, inplace=True)

# Reset the index of the resulting DataFrame
model_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

With this code i was expecting getting the desired dataframe, but the only thing it does is either leave all the data from the player1 and player2 columns in the same place or switch the data from all the player1 columns to the player2 columns and the player2 data to the player1 columns. It switches either all the lines or none of them, when i need some of them switched and some none. The resulting dataframe looks like this:

| tourney_name | draw_size | player2_id | player2_age | player1_id | player1_age | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 32 | 10002 | 18 | 10001 | 23 | 1 |
| A | 32 | 10004 | 30 | 10003 | 24 | 0 |
| A | 32 | 10006 | 28 | 10005 | 25 | 0 |
| B | 64 | 10002 | 18 | 10003 | 24 | 1 |
| B | 64 | 10001 | 23 | 10006 | 28 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to invert two columns 'a' and 'b' according to column 'target':

```
from random import getrandbits

df['target'] = pd.Series([bool(getrandbits(1)) for _ in range(len(df))])
df['a'], df['b'] = (
    df['a'] * df['target'] + df['b'] * ~df['target'],
    df['b'] * df['target'] + df['a'] * ~df['target']
)
```